# How to insert all the rows of a specified set of columns from 1 table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL n00b trying to figure out how to do the following without writing a loop.

I have 2 tables like

```
      First                        Second
=================       ============================ 
 Id |   Name             Id | FirstId | DisplayName
=================       ============================
 1  |  'foo'            
-----------------
 2  |  'bar'
----------------
 3  |  'baz'
```

and I want a query that places a row in `Second` for every row in `First`, like

```
      First                        Second
=================       ============================ 
 Id |   Name             Id | FirstId | DisplayName
=================       ============================
 1  |  'foo'             1  |   3     | 'bazness' 
-----------------       ----------------------------
 2  |  'bar'             2  |   1     | 'fooness'
----------------        ----------------------------
 3  |  'baz'             3  |   2     | 'barness'
```

So the formula was: for each row `f` in `First`, add a row in `Second` with `f.Id` as `FirstID` and `f.Name + 'ness'` as `DisplayName`.

Answer (score 2):

You just want `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into second (firstId, DisplayName)
    select id, name + 'ness'
    from first;
```

Note:  This assumes that `second.id` is declared as an identity column.  If not:

```
insert into second (id, firstId, DisplayName)
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)), id, name + 'ness'
    from first;
```